# Print all lines matching a pattern and within a delimeter

Tags: perl, sed, awk

I have a file containing lines as below.

```
#user

codecodecodecodecodecodecodecode
codecodecodecodecodecodecodecode
codecodecodecodecodecodecodecode
codecodecodecodecodecodecodecode;

#user1

code1code1code1code1code1code1
code1code1code1code1code1code1
code1code1code1code1code1code1
code1code1code1code1code1code1;

#user2

code2code2code2code2code2code2
code2code2code2code2code2code2
code2code2code2code2code2code2
code2code2code2code2code2code2;

#user (again "user" but with a different code)

code3code3code3code3code3code3
code3code3code3code3code3code3
code3code3code3code3code3code3
code3code3code3code3code3code3;
```

I want extract only codes from the "`user`", the output I'm looking for is:

```
#user

codecodecodecodecodecodecodecode
codecodecodecodecodecodecodecode
codecodecodecodecodecodecodecode
codecodecodecodecodecodecodecode;

#user

code3code3code3code3code3code3
code3code3code3code3code3code3
code3code3code3code3code3code3
code3code3code3code3code3code3;
```

Results retuned only the lines matching "user" and its respective codes.

I tried `awk -F";" '{print $1}' $file` but i cant isolate codes from a specific user.

Comment: Please show what you have tried and explain why it doesn't work. Please also explain what you mean by *"until the field delimiter"*, and give a comprehensive example including the output.

Comment: Your edit doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 2):

In a perl one liner:

```
perl -ne 'print if /^#/' in.txt
```

Comment: Or even `grep -v '^#' in.txt`.

Comment: @AndyLester -  Wanted to stick within the tags...

Comment: No knock on you.  Sometimes people asking for help limit themselves in ways they don't need to, so I like to provide those alternatives as well.

Comment: This doesn't seem to account for whatever is meant by *"until it reaches the field delimiter"*

Comment: I want extract only codes within the file that match a pattern, so If I was wating the codes from text it would print:

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk as follows:

```
awk -F\; '/code/' test.txt
```

Assuming the field delimiter is `;` and the pattern is `code`.

If you want to print a particular line or column, use awk's NR and NF variables respectively.

For more info: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html